# What is a way of creating a reactive grid with dynamic rows

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So basically, I have a react app and I am trying to create a grid of square elements but:

1. i dont want to
   shrink them below a certain size (meaning that when the page
   shrinks, the last elements on a row are pushed to the next row
   etc.).
2. I was also hoping to put in a few special 2x2 elements in the grid (realistically not 
   many, between 1-3)

I am looking to be able input a series of objects (ordered by priority) and have the page dynamically allocate them into the grid space as best it can.

I have done bootstrap grids in the past, 1. could be achieved fairly easily by changing the .col-x value at certain screen widths so the elements wrap

But 2. seems really hard:

- making a static row with a 2x2 element and some 1x1 elements seems
  easy, but then it will all break when the above row tries to wrap, or
  when i have to wrap elements in this static row.
- I was also thinking of offsetting 2 consecutive rows and just placing a div with the 2x2 boxes over the offset, but then i would have to change the row elements that are being offset on the fly, and i dont know how to get an element to tell me what row and column it is in.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using bootstrap?

Comment: Sounds like a job for flexbox https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-build-a-responsive-image-gallery-with-flexbox/ or css-grid https://w3bits.com/css-grid-masonry/

Comment: @dorriz oooh nice, Ill have a read through, that looks really promising.